# how to check if an action has been loaded into photoshops action pallete already?

Tags: javascript, action, photoshop

How to check to see if an action has been loaded into the photoshop CS3 action pallete, When I am running my script i have the line.

This is in Javascript.

```
app.load(File("ationFile.atn"));
```

but when ever i run the script it loads the actions into the pallete again, regardless if there is another one there.

What ive been trying to do is create a IF statement that checks for the action in the action pallete, and then if its not there then load it, else resume with the code.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XTools library has an ActionPalette object that will give you what you want I believe. Looking at the SaveActionSets.jsx file in the library you'd use the following snippet to get all the currently loaded sets:

```
  var pal = new ActionsPalette();
  pal.readRuntime();

  var sets = pal.actionSets;
```

Library is here: http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html